# Simple LED Low Voltage Indicator for Li-ion cell (3.3 V threshold)

Tags: led, low-voltage

I'm working on a handheld project that runs off a single cell 3.7V Li-ion cell.  I would like to trigger an LED to turn on when its voltage drops down to 3.3 V.  I have seen other answers with a TL431 IC that uses the a voltage divider to set the threshold (if I'm understanding the circuit correctly). I have access to a regulated 3.3 V line to reference as the threshold.

Can someone point me to a circuit/IC that uses that regulated 3.3 V line to "turn on" the LED when the Li-ion cell drops down to that threshold?  Or would the circuit with the TL431 IC suffice in my application?

Comment: user346278 - Your username has been reset as the previous one was unacceptable. You can change your username, but please do not choose anything vulgar, offensive or otherwise unacceptable in the [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct). Even if intended as a joke misspelling, remember that we have young people visiting the site and we want this to be a welcoming environment for everyone. Thanks for your cooperation.

Answer (score 3):

A TL431 is an excellent solution in many cases if you can tolerate the continuous low current drain from the divider.

A comparator will do what you want and some low current ones impose far less load than a TL431 or TLV431.

A comparator that should work is the [Microchip MCP6541](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP6541%20Output%20SubMicroamp%20Comparators%2020001696K.pdf).
This part was chosen due to its rail to rail input and very low quiescent current.

Untried circuit. D1 is a Schottky diode to prevent CMP1 + input being above Vbat IF battery voltage continues to fall after the LED lights BUT in most cases you will want to stop battery discharge at bout that point.  Schottky diodes have significant leakage at higher temperatures which would raise the reference voltage slightly when Vbattery is higher than Vref - which would not affect operation.
Quiescent current is under 1 microamp, and output drive is up to 30 m A.
[In stock at Digikey](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/products/filter/linear/comparators/692?s=N4IgjCBcoLQExVAYygFwE4FcCmAaEA9lANogCsIAugL7X4KSkC2SADgGxkAsV%2BF0IVlDD5WQyHDJ0Q7RCACWAEyggYYAAwRRqFSHwBHVAE8VWkMdbYVAQwDOKWkA)  for 80 cents in 1's.
R1 = R2. Maybe 100k.
Input error (offset) voltage is +/- 7.5 mV max, +/- 1.5 mV typical.
ie trip point is between +/- 7.5 mV of Vref.
Using 100k for R1 & R2 adds about 0.5 mV to that error.
.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKA3v7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

[This 2014 SEEE answer from Spehro](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/103635/3288)  shows how to use a TL431.
Operation from 3V3 would be marginal, evn with  red LED. Use of a TLV431 at half the sense voltage would be better.
R1 R2 R3 changed to suit.

[image]

Using the TL431 to drive a high side PNP transistor to operate the LED would allow a white LED to be used.
Kluged from diagram [here](https://www.radiolocman.com/shem/schematics.html?di=500327)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Do you have an example circuit for the comparator?

Comment: @user346278 See addition. The 5 pin TSSOP  IC package is almost user friendly.  Tiny - but only 5 pins. Hard but not impossible to hand solder.  Or available in [DIP package](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/products/filter/linear/comparators/692?s=N4IgjCBcpgTAnBaIDGUBmBDANgZwKYA0IA9lANogIAsA7AKz0gC6xADgC5QgDKHATgEsAdgHMQAX2IBaWFFBpIAgK5FSFEE2YSpVDQFsUbAGz1qLYk2RsoYdjcix6u4-JCCAJt2lgADBHYuSBAQYgBHDgBPbgCQKLZ8bkxcNB0gA) for slightly more.

Comment: The current of the circuit draining the battery will ruin the battery.

Comment: @Audioguru Which circuit of the 3? || The top circuit current drain is about 0.6 uA typical, 1 uA max, or about 9 mAh per year. That's under 0.5% of a typical LiIon 18650 cell. 1% of a small prismatic. || Given that he has a 3V3 reference circuit available I assume the aim is to indicate when his LiIon cell is close to depleted. ie hours to days probably. || The second circuit with suitable R1 R2 R3 has quiescent current well under 100 uA with my recommended TLV431. About  2 mAh per day - not good long term. .|| The 3rd circuit about the same with a TLV431. TL431 is several times higher.

Comment: At only 3.3V, a lithium-ion cell is almost dead and is close to the 3.0V when it should have its load disconnected. The current in the LED will soon kill the battery. www.batteyuniversity.com

Comment: @Audioguru Yes-ish. Good points. It does need to be designed properly and not just implemented blindly. That comment may be better on the original question as that is his specification.  See addition to my anwer: